# All methods on some object c++

Tags: c++, dev-c++

In Visual Studio people press ctrl space to see what can do on object. So I am thinking how can I do that in Dev-cpp 4.9.9.2? Example stackstak; And when I wrote stak and press . hwo can I see all method like top pop and etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to enable auto-complete, for that go to

```
Tools > Edit Options > Calss browsing > Completion > Enable code-completion
```

After you type a `.` or a `->` after an object variable or pointer or the first letters of the method you want to use, you can hit `Ctrl+space` an you'll get the auto-complete suggestions of that class. Look [here](http://www.cpp-home.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=5799) for more tips.

Note that this feature is very buggy. I would suggest you use another IDE for your developments, for example [Eclipse for C/C++](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/c.php).

[image]

[image]